# Test that observed percentages differ from theoretical distribution (e.g. 50%)

Tags: percentage

I have a series of independent measurement of a percentage of binary events.
(e.g. 60%, 65%, 55%, 59%, 60%).

How can I test that the observed distribution is different from a theoretical of 50%.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you have the original counts of the binary events that yeld the percentages?